# SetTags didn't strip invalid characters but throw SoftLayer_Exception_InvalidValue

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I used API:  https://softlayer.github.io/reference/services/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest/setTags/ to tag my virtual guest. And API returned error: SoftLayer_Exception_InvalidValue: Invalid value provided for 'tags'. Invalid tag names: created_at:2018-10-08t13:31:57+02:00.

And I noticed that `The characters permitted are A-Z, 0-9, whitespace, _ (underscore), - (hypen), . (period), and : (colon). All other characters will be stripped away.` from https://softlayer.github.io/reference/services/SoftLayer_Tag/setTags/

I thought these two API had same behaviour. But these invalid characters didn't be stripped away.

Are they different API results? Or should I use `SoftLayer_Tag/setTags/` to strip invalid characters?

Answer (score 0):

I did API tests using both methods using the string you provided, and I verified that the behavior for both methods are the same.

Currently, both methods display the exact exception error you provided just as the Portal UI does, instead of stripping invalid characters as mentioned in the [SoftLayer_Tag::setTags](https://softlayer.github.io/reference/services/SoftLayer_Tag/setTags/) documentation, this was reported already, although there isn´t an estimated time of when the SLDN docs will be updated properly.